# What is a Wordpress Term

Tags: wordpress

I know it's a simple enough question, but after spending a fair amount of time trying to google this Question, I can't seem to find a straightforward answer.

What is a Wordpress Term?? I know it's somehow related to taxonomy groups, but what is it??

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, a term are the individual values under a taxonomy.

A taxonomy is like a `category` or `tag`. Those are the default taxonomy types in Wordpress.

`Terms` are the individual values you create under the taxonomy. So if I were doing a programming blog, I could "categorize" my posts with `terms` such as "Wordpress", "PHP", "MySQL", etc. I could do the same with "tags." The `terms` under the "category" and "tag" taxonomies are not related. So I could have a both a"category" and "tag" `term` called "Wordpress".

If you are using `custom post types` you can create your own taxonomies, such as `food` if you were making a lunch post type. Then I could have `terms`, such as "Vegetarian", "Burgers", or "Italian" for example.

Comment: awesome.. cheers dude

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress taxonomy is like a grouping mechanism.

If you have a page with posts, you can notice that the table wp_term_relationships would have a term_taxonomy_id for every post, which has a corresponding term_id in wp_term_taxonomy table. This term_id would have a unique name in wp_terms table.

For ex: Each post in a page can have its own taxonomy like 'category' or 'tag'. The post could also relate to some unique term like 'Expedia'..